# Not getting annotation processed (generated) sources compiled into apk, using maven

Tags: android, maven, annotations, annotation-processing, android-annotations

I try to use Maven and [androidannotations](http://androidannotations.org) to build my apk, but independently of any IDE (I'm actually using IntelliJ IDEA and not Eclipse, but I would like to have it entirely IDE-independent, so that it would also work perfectly on any build server).

The annotations seem to get processed properly, but **they're not being compiled into the apk**, which is where I'm currently stuck.

I try to use the `<includes>` section in the `maven-compiler-plugin`, and the path should be correct - it exists and also contains the annotation processed, generated, java class, which is the Android main activity but with a underscore (_) suffix.

There is a wiki page description how to use Maven+Eclipse, but it's too much bound to the Eclipse IDE. https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Maven-Eclipse
so it doesn't help me solve the problem.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>de-mycompany-myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>com-mycompany-base-myproject</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>2.3.3</platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <classifier>api</classifier>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/apt/**</include>
                        <!--<include>target/generated-sources/apt/**</include>-->
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies/>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`mvn install` even shows me the `-s` compiler option with the correct path:

```
[INFO] javac option: -proc:only
[INFO] javac option: -processor
[INFO] javac option: com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor
[INFO] javac option: -d
[INFO] javac option: /Users/myuser/path/to/com.mycompany.myproject/target/classes
[INFO] javac option: -s
[INFO] javac option: /Users/myuser/path/to/com.mycompany.myproject/target/generated-sources/apt
[INFO] diagnostic Note: Starting AndroidAnnotations annotation processing
[INFO] diagnostic warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
[INFO] diagnostic Note: Dummy source file: file:///Users/path/to/com.mycompany.myproject/target/generated-sources/apt/dummy1341816057285.java
[INFO] diagnostic Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found: /Users/myuser/path/to/com.mycompany.myproject/AndroidManifest.xml
[INFO] diagnostic Note: Number of files generated by AndroidAnnotations: 1
[INFO] diagnostic Note: Generating source file: com.mycompany.myproject.activity.HelloAndroidActivity_
```

(The complete log of `mvn install` is here: http://pastebin.com/6dQkcNXD)

But still running the apk fails with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6942): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myproject.activity.HelloAndroidActivity_ in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

and the annotation processed `HelloAndroidActivity_` is not inside the apk / classes.dex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem: `<extensions>true</extensions>` was missing under `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.2</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
           <includes>
               <include>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/apt/**</include>
           </includes>
       </configuration>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: What exactly does the <extensions> tag mean?

Comment: See this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/maven-android-developers/U15oIcNuR-g and http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Extensions

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I've determined that my original answer was incorrect.

The problem actually lies in the generated `.classpath` file. See: https://gist.github.com/cwc/5224145

In that example, `broken_cp.xml` causes the processed annotations to not be included in the APK when used as `.classpath`. Changing its contents to that of `working_cp.xml` and refreshing the project (prompting a build) immediately fixes the APK issue, and I can launch my Android app from Eclipse successfully.

The broken form of the classpath file is regenerated every time I use the **Maven > Update Project...** project menu option to reload POM files. I'm working around the issue by paying close attention to updates to the `.classpath` file, and making sure I don't commit a broken version.